# Android: How to get the last known location in foreground service?

Tags: java, android

I want to get the last known location in a foreground service every time I need. There is a Kotlin code that works perfectly according to [this](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current) tutorial. :

```
private fun getlastknownlocation(){
    val client: FusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
    client.lastLocation
            .addOnSuccessListener { location : Location? ->

                // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
            }
}
```

So I want to do the same using java and here is my code:

```
public class myService extends Service {

    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
       ...
       ...
       ...
   void getLocation() {

        fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                .addOnSuccessListener(WHATSHOULDBEHERE, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Location location) {

                        // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                        if (location != null) {
                           //

                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

So ...

> WHATSHOULDBEHERE

I tried `(Executor/Activity) getApplication()` ,`(Executor/Activity) getApplicationContext()`, `(Executor) myService.this` and got this error:

> androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication/myService cannot be cast to
> java.util.concurrent.Executor

How can I get last known or even current location in foreground service using java? Note that I don't want to track or get location data periodically.

**UPDATE**:
I removed first parameter and now I get no errors. But still can't get location. I wonder that it's possible with kotlin code easily, And I can't do that with java code. Here is my Kotlin code:

```
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
private fun requestLocation() {
    val request = LocationRequest()
    request.numUpdates = 1
    request.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
    val client: FusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

    client.requestLocationUpdates(request, object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
            val location: Location = locationResult.lastLocation
            if (location != null) {
                Log.i("Location Service", "location update $location")
            }
        }
    }, null)

}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
private fun getlastknownlocation(){
    val client: FusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
    client.lastLocation
            .addOnSuccessListener { location : Location? ->
                Log.i("location11", location?.latitude.toString())
                Log.i("location11", location?.longitude.toString())

                // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
            }
}
```

and here is my `manifests.xml`:

```
<service
    android:name=".myService"
    android:foregroundServiceType="location"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:stopWithTask="false" />
```

Comment: Perhaps you pass an instance of [an `Executor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor). For example, you could [call `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors#newSingleThreadExecutor()). Or, remove that first parameter, and [call the one-parameter version of `addOnSuccessListener()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task#addOnSuccessListener(com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener%3C?%20super%20TResult%3E)).

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks. now There is no errors but still I can't get location. Would you please answer question with details for getting location (last known and accurate location) in a service so I can accept that.

Comment: WHATSHOULDBEHERE? Nothing, call the same method you're calling from Kotlin that only has one argument. Note that your Kotlin code is actually calling a Java API.

Comment: @m0skit0 OK! please read UPDATE. I know and I tried decompile kotlin bytecode to java code and I wrote java code based on that. But still not worked.